# Different hashCode() in debug and normal Java execution

Tags: java, hashcode

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new boolean[] {}.hashCode());
}
```

In normal run result is always 189568618

In debug result is always 321142942

In debug means "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:50524,suspend=y,server=n"

Why?

(azul-21.0.2)

##### Update:

it is not IDE/Maven issue. It is commandline output (numbers are different than in IDE)

> md5sum Ops.class
>
> 0cd9aa057204d816ea1a1edf4eb9f792 *Ops.class
>
> java Ops
>
> 681842940
>
> java Ops
>
> 681842940
>
> java
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 Ops
>
> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
>
> 1555845260
>
> java
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 Ops
>
> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
>
> 1555845260
>
> md5sum Ops.class
>
> 0cd9aa057204d816ea1a1edf4eb9f792 *Ops.class

Comment: What is meant by "In debug"? And according the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()): "This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application."

Comment: OK, good catch. But is there any explanation why this integer remains consistent across execution in the same mode (normal vs debug)?

Comment: I have a hunch that maybe your build tool / IDE caches the built binary, like Gradle's [build cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html):
_The build cache works by storing (locally or remotely) build outputs and allowing builds to fetch these outputs from the cache when it is determined that inputs have not changed, avoiding the expensive work of regenerating them._

Comment: Some of us on Stack Overflow claim the default hash code is a memory address, or based on a memory address. That isn't necessarily the case, but it is allowed to be the case. My guess is it is the case in your case. The memory locations are different, and hence the hash codes, because of the need to store more information for debug mode.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Sadly most of these caching mechanisms are hidden by the IDE so we can only make the best assumptions based on the output we are seeing. OP can run an experiment and clear the local cache of the IDE and re-run to see if the hashcodes change

Comment: You should not be thinking about hash codes in a way which makes you even interested in asking this question.

Comment: @tgdavies I agree but it's too late and I become curious how it works

Comment: @TP95 "hidden by the IDE"? Most probably not written in Java, but provided in native code, compiled from C

Comment: This is *definitely* all implemented in native code in the OpenJDK code base.  Anyone who is curious *should* read Aleksey Shipilëv's article and/or the OpenJDK source code.  With great curiosity comes great responsibility ... to do your own research!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Java 11 javadocs<sup>1</sup> for `hashCode()`:

> (The hashCode may or may not be implemented as some function of an object's memory address at some point in time.)

In earlier versions of Java it typically was based on a memory address.  In newer versions it typically IS NOT based on an address.  I think that the current default is to use a [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).   For more information<sup>2</sup> see this:

- [*JVM Anatomy Quark<sup>3</sup> #26: Identity Hash Code*](https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/26-identity-hash-code/)

So ... to understand precisely why >you< get different hashCode values for the same object, you would need to find out which of the alternative hashCode algorithms is being used in your JVM(s).

But either way, there is nothing *in the javadoc* to say that the identity hashcode of an object will be the same from one run to the next.  What you are observing is an implementation artifact.  It is something you shouldn't rely on.

---

<sup>1 - Other versions of the javadoc say different things.  The latest versions remove all mention of how the hashCode is generated.

2 - It is possible that Aleksey's article is out of date. If it really matters to you, download the OpenJDK source code and do your own analysis.

3 - That's what Aleksey wrote on the page!</sup>

Comment: In other words, a feature, not a bug.